# How to select text in WebPreviewer?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

When we click a document in Share, another page opens (document-details) with a preview of this document in flash.
By default, we can't select text (for copy/paste) in that preview, and I would like to know if this is possible and how ?
Perhaps I should use another previewer, or use the default one with a specific parameter ?!
I searched the web, and saw that this functionnality is present in flash, but can't find how to implement that with the WebPreviewer.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Media Viewers](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/media-viewers) add-on on Share Extras provides an alternative document viewer based on [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/)

Assuming you are using Alfresco 4.0, the add-on allows you to view document outlines, thumbnails and pages. In the pages you can select text and perform searches.

I am one of the contributors to this add-on and we would welcome feedback via the project site.

Comment: Since my request, if found your add-on and already tested it.
This is a great feature and will use it rather than the default viewer. I found some bugs and I'll give you my feedbacks soon.
There is one thing missing I think, it would be cool to be able to put that viewer not only on document-details but also on any other page easily, for example, on edit-metadata.

Can you tell me the exact place where you want my feedbacks ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That sounds like great feedback, thanks. The best place to put those is as issues on the Google Code project - http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/issues/list

Comment: Feedbacks sent. I think you have enough stuff for this WE ;-)